# Spring profiles: Repository bean cannot be autowired

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I'm having issues when trying to run a JUnit Test with some Spring profile I've created. Actually, profiles do work fine, except for a repository bean, which cannot be autowired.

This is the fragment of code I use to configure persistence in spring-integration-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
   .... Some namespaces definitions

    <beans profile="dev">
        <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2" />

        <!-- Define the JPA transaction manager -->
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        </bean>


        <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="vendorAdaptor" />
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="guiatv.persistence.*" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="abstractVendorAdaptor" abstract="true">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="database" value="H2" />
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="entityManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="vendorAdaptor"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
            parent="abstractVendorAdaptor">
        </bean>
    </beans>

    ... Some other beans, some of them with the same "dev" profile

</beans>
```

So I though it would be enough by wrapping the whole persistence configuration with a "beans profile" element.

Now, from my JUnit test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ApplicationTest.class)
@ActiveProfiles("dev")

public class ScheduleLoaderTests {
    @Autowired
    ScheduleLoader schedLoader;

    @Autowired
    ScheduleRepository shedRep;

    @Test
    public void someTest() { ... }
}
```

And then I'm annotating my ApplicationTest class with:

> @ImportResource("classpath:/META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-context.xml")

But when I run the test, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [guiatv.persistence.repository.ScheduleRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Note that in my test class, the ScheduleLoader is previously autowired,indeed that bean is also within dev profile. If I try to run the test without 
**@ActiveProfiles("dev")** annotation, then the exception is thrown by **ScheduleLoader failed autowiring**, as expected (since it's only in dev profile).

So what's the problem with spring profiles and my persistence configuration?

PD: I have ensured that my repository and entity class are within that

> guiatv.persistence.*

package.

By the way, I'm using Spring Boot, so I also tried to make it work by adding **spring.profiles.active=dev** on my application.properties file instead of writing 
**@ActiveProfiles("dev") annotation**.

**UPDATE**

Also, if I try to remove every "beans profile" elements, so that every component is a child of the root "beans" element, everything is working fine, either with no @ActiveProfiles("dev") annotation or with @ActiveProfiles("default") annotation.

Comment: Where is the part where you configure the repositories (i guess, those are repositories from Spring Data JPA)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's working.

@dunni what you see is the whole persistence related configuration. And yes, I use JPA, but as I said, I'm using Spring Boot. It seems Spring Boot configures **persistence.xml** for you (and I guess that's what you were asking about).

So, the only thing missing was the **@SpringBootApplication** on my ApplicationTest class, in order to make the repositories been autoconfigured by Spring Boot.

And sorry for my confusing UPDATE, where I was missing **@SpringBootApplication** too.